# Compile time/runtime addition

Tags: java

`X z = new Y();` means that at compile time it will treat `z` as an instance of `class X`, but at runtime as an instance of `class Y`.

So why is: `z.method((byte)0 + (char)0);` dealt with at runtime? Aren't these just 2 constants being added up, so it can be determined at compile time, instead of runtime?

```
class X {
    void method(int x) { System.out.println("X:int"); }
}

class Y extends X {
    void method(int x) { System.out.println("Y:int"); }
}

public class Z {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        X x = new X();
        X z = new Y();

        System.out.println("1:");
        z.method((byte)0 + (char)0);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1:
Y:int
```

Comment: Hint for newbies: you are expected to do prior research. And especially when you are new here/to java: chances are very high that you are not the first person to ask this question. So before spending 15 minutes to write up a good question, spent just a few minutes to check if this question was asked before.

Comment: I know, but how am I supposed to know all the applicable terms?

Comment: I don't know why the revision history doesn't show it anymore but to others: the original question was about passing `null` to an overloaded method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how the addition is relevant. You have a method add() in X taking an int as parameter. This method is overridden in Y. `z`references an object whose concrete type is Y, so the overriding method in Y is called. That's just plain old polymorphism.

Comment: Yep that is it, although that last sentence was unnecessary.